# Musescore - only export score (not tab)

Tags: musescore

I like to export the piano score from a file. Right now I see both scores and tabs. Is there a way to hide the tabs?

I have v2.1

[image: musescore-screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit menu >> Instruments
In the Instruments palette, uncheck the Visible box against your tablature stave.
Click OK.

This will only hide the tablature & allow you to export or save without it, it won't delete it.